# Database structure

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a database structure in the below format,

subjects table

```
subject_id subject_name
    1         HTML
    2         Java
```

chapters table

```
chapter_id chapter_name subject_id
    1      Doctype          1
    2      Intro to Java    2
```

tutorials table

```
tutorial_id tutorial_name       chapter_id subject_id
     1      Intro to doctype         1         1
     2      Details of doctype       1         1
     3      Intro to JVM             2         2
```

should subject_id be in tutorials table?

Comment: You can get some idea by googling as star schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can get it indirectly from the chapters table. It's redundant in the tutorial table.

Answer (score 3):

No need of Using it as its chapter id is available in chapter table

Answer (score 2):

No need of using it. If you do it, its like forming a circle. Just remove subject id from the tutorial table.